# Azure VM compute hours more than 24 hours per day

Tags: azure

I Have an Azure VM. I am using approximately 9 hours per day. However I downloaded the usage report today and it shows 42 hours for one specific day and there are some day it is more than 30. Is this charge based on number of cores? My A1 VM got 4 cores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really a programming question and this site is for programming questions... but yes, Azure charges for number of cores per day. You're not charged if your VM is in "Stopped and Deallocated" mode only.  Otherwise, you get charged for all the cores per minute, regardless of how much they're used.

Comment: Sorry I reached to StackOverflow from my Azure portal. Thanks, Is there any link in windowsazure.com detailing this. I could not find charges by core in pricing page.

Comment: Here is a link for VM pricing.  Make sure to pick your region: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/

Comment: Thanks @Igorek. Azure is simpler in many Areas. However the usage report shows computing hours by Cores, but in the calculator compute hours is based entire VM, but cost wise there is no surprise. I have to divide total hours by number of cores to get the proper compute hours. Thanks again for solving this big confusion. Now all Azure dashboard graphs makes sense.